# How to extract in perl just a part of a string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable that contains a path like this:

```
$Path = "C:/Work/Job_V14/Myfile";
```

This variable can change each time I run the code. The only thing that never changes is that in the Path I will always have _V and 2 digit (like in this case _V14).

How can I obtain from the path only the part _V+2 digit?

Comment: If you want to program with Perl, you will surely need to be able to write regex yourself. I _strongly_ recommend that you read through (at least) "Part 1: the basics" of [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match the substring, like so

```
$Path = "C:/Work/Job_V14/Myfile";

if ( $Path =~ m[ ( _V \d\d [/\\] ) ]x )
{
    my $match = $1 ;
    print "Matched '$match'\n";
}
else
{
    print "No match\n";
}
```

Above assumes that _V+2digit can never appear anywhere else in the string. If that is the case, the regular expression needs to be revisited.

Comment: `[/\\]` would be better than `/`, seeing as both `\ ` and `/` are valid directory separators in Windows. You might even want to use `(?: [/\\] | \z )` to support `C:/Work/Job_V14`.

Comment: please can you explain me better how should you write it with an example? Thanks

Comment: @Dana, Literally replace `/` with `(?: [/\\] | \z )` as I said and for the reasons I said.

Comment: @Dana, the enhancements suggested will certainly make the code more robust. Whether they make sense for your use-case depends on the nature of your input data and whether this is throwaway code that will only ever get run once. One of the key questions is whether your input data can ever contain a windows path that uses "\" as the path delimiter, rather that the Linux/Unix form "/".

Comment: the path should be in linux or windows it depends. In any case I do this: 
   $PathProduct = abs_path($0);                                                        
   $PathProduct =~ m/(EPVZLINUX_V\d{2})/;
    @Elem_Version = split('_V', $1);
    $ProdVers = @Elem_Version[1]; and it works as I expected. Thanks

Comment: updated the answer to allow "/" or "\" path delimeters.

Answer (score 2):

If the path will always be a file in the directory whose name you want, I'd start with the following:

```
use Path::Class qw( file );

my path = "C:/Work/Job_V14/Myfile";
my $project = file($path)->dir->basename;   # Job_V14
```

Now, we us a match to extract the version.

```
my ($version) = $project =~ /_V(\d+)\z/;    # 14
```

Comment: [Path::Tiny would be a better choice](https://xdg.me/blog/goodbye-path-class-hello-path-tiny/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$Path = "C:/Work/Job_V14/Myfile";

# this code makes the assumption that your _Vxx contains the first _ in the path string
my $first; my $second; my $result ;

($first, $second) = split('_',$Path,2);   # split off the part before _
($result) = split('/',$second) ;   # takes only the first element 
$result = "_" . $result ; #adding back the _

print $result . "\n" ;  # prints _V14
```

If you have multiple occurrences of _ before your _Vxx, then this code needs an adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following piece of code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while( <DATA> ) {
    say $1 if m!(_V\d{2})/!;
}

__DATA__
C:/Work/Job_V14/Myfile
C:/Work/Project_01/Job_V12/SomeFile
C:/Work/Project_03/Job_V02/SomeFile
C:/Work/Job_V34/SomeFile
```

Output:

```
_V14
_V12
_V02
_V34
```